# LibreOffice touch screen scrolling on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: libreoffice, scrolling

I use LibreOffice on Ubuntu 18.04. Touch screen scrolling doesn't seem to work in the app (I have it working outside the app and in other apps such as Firefox). In LibreOffice it just highlights text (like a mouse would do). Is there a way to enable touch screen scrolling in LibreOffice?

Comment: for me the same is true for Kubuntu 20.04.
has anybody any hints if it is possible at all?